# Sed word duplication problem

Tags: sed

I'm new to sed and trying out stuff to learn. However I'm encountering a problem I can't solve when using sed to remove duplicate words :

```
echo "abc abc def ghi ijk ijk" | sed 's/\([a-z][a-z]*\) \1/\1/g'
```

outputs

```
abc def ghijk ijk
```

and it does that everytime a word finishes with the same letter as the first letter of the following word. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: For your information, [a-z][a-z]* can be written more consisely as [a-z]+

Comment: @StiegHemmer $ echo "abc abc def ghi ijk ijk" | sed 's/\<\([a-z]+-\)\> \<\1\>/\1/g'
 => abc abc def ghi ijk ijk

Comment: It was just supposed to be [a-z]+, the minus/hyphen is just part of the site layout.

Comment: Oh right my bad :)

Comment: For advanced regular expressions, the `-r` option may be usefull: `sed -r 's/\b([a-z]+)\b \b\1\b/\1/g'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that, as is, the regex can match partial words.  In the example you show, it is matching the `i` at the end of one word with the `i` at the beginning of the next.  The solution is to insist that the regex match whole words:

```
$ echo "abc abc def ghi ijk ijk" | sed 's/\<\([a-z][a-z]*\)\> \<\1\>/\1/g'
abc def ghi ijk
```

In GNU sed, `\<` matches at the beginning of a word and `\>` matches at the end of a word.

#### More complex matches

In the example in the question, the regex was matching on a single repeated character, `i i`.  Here is an example where it matches `oat oat`:

```
$ echo "smoat oats" | sed 's/\([a-z][a-z]*\) \1/\1/g'
smoats
```

This is, again, fixed by insisting on whole words:

```
$ echo "smoat oats" | sed 's/\<\([a-z][a-z]*\)\> \<\1\>/\1/g'
smoat oats
```

#### Simplification

Since alphabet to space transitions always mark a word boundary, the part of the regex above that uses `\> \<` is unnecessary because the regex requires that the characters on both sides are alphabetic.  Thus, we could use:

```
$ echo "smoat oats" | sed 's/\<\([a-z][a-z]*\) \1\>/\1/g'
smoat oats
```

#### Documentation

For more information on the subtleties of sed and its regular expressions, I recommend the [Grymoire tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html).  The ultimate reference for GNU sed is the [GNU sed manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html).

Comment: Thanks, is it just me or is sed documentation a bit light ? I can't seem to find much...

Comment: @Mr.Smith Yes, the `man sed` is light.  I updated the answer with links to two references that I find to be much more informative.